# RF choke in Limiter Design

Tags: rf, inductor

I am studying about limiter...

[image]

(pic from Skyworks 200480C.pdf)

In a limiter design, how should I design the RF choke inductor?

If I need to design a limiter at 1-4 GHz and have a spiral inductor as RF choke, I would need a big spiral inductor so that it works better at low frequency but it can't be too big so that its self-resonance frequency won't overlap with the in-band frequency, right?

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: First, just to be sure, you realize the two ground symbols in the schematic indicate RF grounds that aren't necessarily at the same DC voltage, right?

Comment: @ThePhoton: As I understand, the use of the Choke is to offer a return path for the rectified DC. So in this circuit the ground signals actually must be connected with each other at DC. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need about 80 nH to get a 500 ohm reactance at 1 GHz.

This seems to be just on the edge of what's reasonable to do with a planar spiral inductor.

But you can likely achieve it with a series combination of two inductors. One with lower value but higher SRF, placed close to the RF trace. The second with a higher value but lower SRF.

You'll want to do some modelling to check how the inductors interact with each other's parasitic capacitance, and you might find some benefit in adding a parallel or shunt resistance to de-queue any resonance.

**Edit** With a bit of searching I found an air coil inductor with 80 nH and 11 GHz SRF, so it is possible to do this with a single part. But the vendor I found isn't anything like cheap.

Comment: Thanks @The Photon for the info. I have couple more questions in mind... Does the SRF inductor need to be much higher than the in-band frequency? Do you have idea about how the inductor self-resonance frequency will affect the insertion loss the limiter? Probably a deep in band?

Comment: SRF shouldn't have to be much higher than the operating band, but you'll want some margin for thermal variation, etc. You'll want to play around with a simulator to find the best part and see its effect.

Comment: @ThePhoton "You'll want to do ..... de-queue any resonance."
This sounds interesting. Could you provide an example for such a situation? I know that is a quite general request... :-) Or maybe a link to read further?

Comment: @Carsten, like I said in the post, if you're designing a bias tee, model it with parasitic capacitance of the inductors. If you find an unacceptable resonance, then a common solution is to add a resistor in parallel with the inductor to reduce the Q factor of the resonance (aka "de-queue" the circuit).

Comment: @ThePhoton: Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like your choke should be in series with the input and output, high frequency stuff that you want to choke will see the parallel inductor as a relatively high impedance, it also appears as a relatively low impedance path to ground for lower frequencies and